# ¿Como puedo hacer un cajero automatico en python con recursividad de Pila?

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas era para ver si me podian ayudar con una practica que tengo y trata de hacer un cajero automatico con recursividad de pila la funcion principal seria asi desglosarBilletes(monto) y tendria que retornar asi [ [ 3, 20000 ] , [ 1, 10000 ], [ 1, 5000 ], [ 1, 2000 ] , [ 1, 1000 ] ]
para ver si me podrian ayudar

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Hola, las preguntas de "como hago esto" que contienen muchas imagenes o que no tienen algo de investigación no son bien aceptadas, además de lo recomendado por el compañero te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic